# Is it possible to run a system with database without using xampp?

Tags: database, xampp

i am sorry if this is a dumb question. 
I am just curious.

Example i have a simple information system that save name, address , age etc.
it save in database name called "info"

My question is, is it possible to run it without running the xampp ?  example i am using vb.net and xampp and create informtion system.

Example i want to use it by 100 people.  Do i need to tell them to install the xampp first and put the database there and run it to run the system ?? Or there are other way to do that.

Comment: Why the users needs to install xamp ?

Comment: Usually, when you are done developing your product, you would host it on a Web service to allow your users to access it. However before you do something like that, you will need to make sure ONLY the right people can use it. If it's just a simple app that people use on their desktops, then you will need a way to install and run a database server on each machine - or use a data service that is native to the OS.

Comment: @Toothgip Because they will import the database in the xampp to run the system ? .

Comment: .
@Jerry so in other words the other users need internet connection to access the data right ?

Answer (score 1):

So depending if you want to host this database locally or over the internet via a remote server, you only need to host the database on a single machine in order to be accessed.

So if you want to host this database on your local computer, you can run on xampp, but other users would need to be able to access your computer in order to reach the database.

On the opposite end, you can have a remote server, serve the database (I am assuming a MySQL server). Which you wouldn't really want to run on xampp, but you definitely can.

Comment: Yes, local only.  So i really need to install the XAMPP to run the system on their computer to use the database i made? . Thank you so much.

Comment: @kim Short answer, yes. Depending on what kind of system they are running, you can run a mysql server locally on each system, as xampp has a bit of overhead. Have you looked into SQLite? It is a database in a single file and might be more than enough for your project

Comment: SQLite is even built right into some operating systems, so no install would be required. I don't know about Windows, though.